# How to test setter in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I am studying about JUnit test. I want to test getter and setter in JUnit, but it doesn't work.
This is the first class.

```
public class Practice {
private String name;

public Practice(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}
and this is the second class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Practice2 {
private ArrayList<Practice> practice;

public Practice2() {
    this.practice = new ArrayList<Practice>();
}

public ArrayList<Practice> getPractice() {
    return this.practice;
}

public void setPractice(ArrayList<Practice> practice) {
    this.practice = practice;
}
}
```

The parameter of setPractice is ArrayList, so I put object of Practice class in the parameter, but It shows an error.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class testGetterAndSetter {

@Test
public void testSetter() {
    Practice2 aaa = new Practice2();
    Practice bbb = new Practice("Hello");
    aaa.setPractice(bbb.setName("A"));
}
}
```

How do I need to change for testing the setter, and how can I test for this?

Comment: `bbb.setName("A")` doesn't returns anything but `aaa.setPractice` expects `ArrayList<Practice>` thus the error.

Comment: bbb.setName doesn't return anything. What exactly are you trying to set? The problem is not your test, it seems rather your lack of understanding of what your code is doing

Comment: I want to test setPractice(ArrayList<Practice). What should I put in here instead of bbb.setName()?

Answer (score 2):

Problem lies here:

```
aaa.setPractice(bbb.setName("A"));
```

`setPractice()` requires argument of `ArrayList`, but `bbb.setName("A")` returns `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have really intricate logic in your getters and setters (which definitely is not the case), Unit Test them are overkill, a waste of time, and a waste of computer resources while performing them.

Focus on your business logic instead. Focus on the classes with not so simple logic and that is the core of your application. Focus less on achieving 100% test coverage and more on thoroughly testing the main parts of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You typically test a setter in combination with testing the corresponding getter.

Set a value, then get it and see if what you get back is what you put in.

Of course such a test is so trivial many people simply omit it, but I exist in an environment where a very high test coverage is mandatory (and you never know whether someone makes a typo in a setter after all...) so it's a good idea to include them (unless of course you have something like Lombok in place that generates getters and setters for you on the fly).